# Removing a range of elements from a priority Queue in Java

Tags: java

How do you remove a range of elements from a priority queue that is ordered by string value? (so for example, in a priority queue for alphabets, the first element is "A", then "B", and so on, and the user may want to remove elements "M" to "Q").

Comment: Hello, have you tried something already?

Comment: @YassinHajaj Hi, I tried giving the strings int value and then removing them in a loop, but it takes so long so I'm looking for a better way.

Comment: If you share what you've tried so far (the sources basically), it'll be easier for us to help

Comment: @YassinHajaj unfortunately I deleted that like an hour ago and couldn't solve it another way.

Answer (score 0):

Since a `PriorityQueue` is only partially sorted, a range of values is not stored together, and thus can not be removed efficiently. If you need efficient removal by range, a different data structure may therefore be a better fit. For instance, with a TreeSet you could do:

```
TreeSet<Whatever> set = ...;
set.subset(from, to).removeAll();
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your contribution! Unfortunately, this is a part of an assignment and we are not supposed to change the data structures defined by the instructor.